# I'm trying to save an array ($sales) into the database

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to save an Array $sales.

Here the data into this Array:

```
sales
    0
        Product
            id146
            category
            descriptiondrei
            created2013-11-20 14:10:12
            modified2013-11-20 14:10:12
            shop_id27
            category_id1
            image(null)
        Shop
            id27
            user_id23
            titlebarby
            descriptionkleines
            created2013-10-29 12:51:32
            modified2013-10-29 12:51:32
        Category
            id1
            imageHaushalt
```

The method in the Controller look like this:

public function save_notepad() {

```
    $sales = array();

    if($this -> Session -> valid() && $this -> Session -> check('notepad')) {
        $notepad = $this -> Session -> read('notepad');
        $this->loadModel('Product');
        $condition = array('Product.id' => $notepad);   
        $sales = $this -> Product-> find('all', array('conditions' => $condition)); 
        }   
    $this -> set('sales', $sales);

     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Sale->create();
        if ($this->Sale->saveall($sales));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The sale has been saved'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
```

The Problem is, that when I save, in the database it saves just the id and the created date.

The Model Looks like this:
class Sale extends AppModel {

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'conditions' => array('Product.id' => 'Sale.product_id'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Shop' => array(
        'className' => 'Shop',
        'foreignKey' => 'shop_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
));
```

}

What do I need to do for saving also the "product_id" and the "shop_id" which are already in the Array $sales?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the array into xml or json and save as single string blob into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

php echo $this->Form>input('product-id', array('type' => 'Text', 'value' => $sales['Product']['ID']));

It needs 'type' bevor 'value'.